# Nservicebus exception handling

Tags: exception, handler, nservicebus

We're using NServiceBus to handle a number of message types. On nservicebus.com they say we should not handle exceptions as NServiceBus will take care of this. Now our problem is this: if we have two message handlers both handling the same type of message and there is an exception in one of the handlers - is it possible to let NServiceBus handle this exception (retry and log) but even if the retries fail we still want the other handler to be run? Or does that mean we have to handle the exception our selfs in handler number one in order to be sure handler number two is always run?

Thanks

/Christian

Clarification:

A simplified version of our scenario: Our system we handle invoices, when an invoice changes status an "InvoiceStatusChanged" message is sent to the nservicebus and two things should happen, a message should be sent to a queue and an email should be sent to the person who is to handle the invoice next. These two things has no dependency on each other.

Maybe we have done some mistake in our set up because if the handler writing a message to the queue is run first and the e-mailing handler crasches at each retry then we end up with five messages on the queue.

We are redesigning so that the status change event sends two different messages to the bus and each handler will handle a separate messagetype.

Thanks

/Christian

Comment: With the risk of sounding like a broken record:) This is design smell, can you give us some more input on the business problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire message handler pipeline is within the transaction boundary.  If any of the handlers fail, then the whole transaction rolls back.  It feels like if you always want the second handler to run it feels like that there should be 2 different messages and therefore 2 different transactions, a different handler in another endpoint also separating them, or maybe you want a Saga to handle the workflow.